# Javascript - compare two arrays with filter as efficient as possible

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, include

I want to compare two arrays with `filter` as efficiently as possible, and also as descriptively as possible.

I am sure there must be a nice way to do this without resorting to `forEach`, but for the life of me I cannot find it, would anyone be kind enough to help me out of my misery?

Scenario

```
mainList array
id : 1, name : 'foo', categories : ["c1","c2","c3"]
id : 2, name : 'bar', categories : ["c1","c4","c5"]
```

userSelectListNames array "foo"

userSelectListCats array "c1","c4"

Filter on mainList categories - this is where I am stuck

```
return mainList.filter(item => userSelectListCats.includes(item.categories));
```

I want the use to see both records if he select "c1" and "c4", or "c1"
And only the last one if he select "c4" and "c5"
But I get hopelessly confused when trying it...

My 2 best tries..

```
return mainList.categories.filter(item => userSelectListCats.includes(item));
```

But it returns categories, and not the mainList.

```
return mainList.filter(item => mainList.categories.filter(item2 => userSelectListCats.includes(item2)));
```

I am sure there must be a nice way to do this without resorting to forEach, but for the life of me I cannot find it, would anyone be kind enough to help me out of my misery?

Comment: Thanks go to hev1 - beautiful solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array#filter` along with `Array#some`.

```js
const arr = [{id : 1, name : 'foo', categories : ["c1","c2","c3"]}, {id : 2, name : 'bar', categories : ["c1","c4","c5"]}];
const userSelectListCats = ["c1", "c4"];
const res = arr.filter(({categories})=>
   userSelectListCats.some(x => categories.includes(x)));
console.log(res);
```